# Android Studio - Firebase Fatal error

Tags: android, loops, android-layout, firebase, fatal-error

### **Can someone tell me what is causing the error:**

**Exception java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.moneyegg.bdpsoft.makemonepaypal/com.moneyegg.bdpsoft.makemonepaypal.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'com.firebase.client.Firebase com.firebase.client.Firebase.child(java.lang.String)' on a null object reference**

> android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity
>   (ActivityThread.java:2236)
>   android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity
>   (ActivityThread.java:2387) android.app.ActivityThread.access$800
>   (ActivityThread.java:151) android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage
>   (ActivityThread.java:1303) android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage
>   (Handler.java:102) android.os.Looper.loop (Looper.java:135)
>   android.app.ActivityThread.main (ActivityThread.java:5254)
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java)
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:372)
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run
>   (ZygoteInit.java:903) com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main
>   (ZygoteInit.java:698)

**Caused by java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'com.firebase.client.Firebase com.firebase.client.Firebase.child(java.lang.String)' on a null object reference**

> com.moneyegg.bdpsoft.makemonepaypal.MainActivity.
>   (MainActivity.java:35)
>   java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance (Constructor.java)
>   java.lang.Class.newInstance (Class.java:1606)
>   android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity (Instrumentation.java:1066)
>   android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity
>   (ActivityThread.java:2226)
>   android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity
>   (ActivityThread.java:2387) android.app.ActivityThread.access$800
>   (ActivityThread.java:151) android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage
>   (ActivityThread.java:1303) android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage
>   (Handler.java:102) android.os.Looper.loop (Looper.java:135)
>   android.app.ActivityThread.main (ActivityThread.java:5254)
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java)
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:372)
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run
>   (ZygoteInit.java:903) com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main
>   (ZygoteInit.java:698)

Comment: Please show your code

Comment: On that activity?

Comment: show your Firebaseservice activity

Answer (score 0):

Change your declaration while accessing child by name from firebase database, have look :

Change your declaration to:

```
private DatabaseReference databaseRef;
and assign value to it after you created mRef

mRef =  FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReferenceFromUrl("xxxxxxxxxxxxxx");
databaseRef= mRef.child("Name");
```

Happy coding!!